# Only able to connect via ethernet. WIFI isn't even an option

Tags: wireless, settings, detect

I have looked through the community but being new gives me a disadvantage...

I have Ubuntu 14.04LTS installed on a Dell Latitude D830

I went to software updates and enabled the broadcom driver
Also enabled the Nvidia driver that was a proprietary driver

I can connect via the ethernet cable, but I have no sign of it detecting anything wireless.
I don't have a switch to cut wifi on/off on this laptop.

I have reset both the modem and router. I looked on here and found a few threads talking about "soft blocked" and other options. I followed them in the terminal but had no success.

Any help is appreciated. If you need more information please let me know what to do next.

```
vinny@Vinnys-PC:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem as you, and in the terminal you can enter:

```
rfkill list
```

show soft and hard block if it is blocked you can enter:

```
rfkill unblock wlan0
```

and then you can in the terminal enter:

```
lspci
```

shows the wireless info, and then in the terminal enter:

```
lsusb wlan0
```

and if it is down then in the terminal enter:

```
ifdown wlan0
lsmod wlan0
```

and it set the wireless to be users, and then you sould scan the port, and in the terminal enter:

```
nmap -v -iR 10000 -Pn -p port
```

and then restart the system and it might work fine.

Comment: I did this as well and it is finally working. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot

Comment: thank you this seems to have worked. when I rebooted it got stuck at a screen and something failed tho. I had to manually turn the pc off

Comment: It had nothing to do with the commands I had you run, please accept the answer so everyone can benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
sudo reboot
```

From the ubuntu forums on a thread concerning 12.10, worked well for me on 14.04 while linux-firmware-nonfree (mentioned in another answer) caused same errors as you, only it did not work at all.